# Android: Emulator -ramdisk command line option is broken

Tags: android, scala, android-emulator

While trying to follow the [Tweaking the Android Emulator](http://lamp.epfl.ch/~michelou/android/emulator-android-sdk.html) to include the Scala libraries natively on the emulator, I can't get the custom ramdisk image to load.  It appears that the emulator -ramdisk command line option is ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Colin on the scala-on-android Google group, he confirmed that there is a defect in the emulator's `-ramdisk` option.

His workaround, which I verified successfully is to copy the `ramdisk.img` to the directory of the AVD that you wish to use.  On Windows, the AVD files are stored at `c:/Users/[UserName]/.android/avd`.  On Linux, they are stored at `~/.android/avd`.

After the `ramdisk.img` is copied, just start the emulator as usual (no `-ramdisk` option is necessary).